Estimating the error in the Taylor series
Let $f\colon\Omega\to\Bbb R$ be an analytic function over its domain $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb R$. Is there, in general, a way to estimate the error? That is, I want to know if there is a general formula for a function $h(n)$ such that
$$\left|f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n\right|\le h(N)$$

The most general estimation I know is
(Theorem 5.3.2, Zorich's Mathematical Analysis I) Let $f(x)\in C^{(n)}[x_0,x]$ with $f^{(n+1)}$ existent on $(x_0,x)$. Then for any $\varphi(x)\in C^{(1)}[x_0,x]$ with $\varphi'(t)\neq0$ for all $t\in(x_0,x)$ there is $\xi\in(x_0,x)$ such that
$$
r_n(x;x_0)=\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(x_0)}{\varphi'(\xi)\cdot n!}f^{(n+1)}(\xi)\cdot(x-\xi)^n
$$
Proof is done by letting $g(t)=r_n(x;t)$ and then apply Cauchy's finite increment theorem on $F$ and $\varphi$ from $x_0$ to $x$.
In this way a candidate of $h$ is given as
$$
h_\varphi(n)=\frac{\left\vert \varphi(x)-\varphi(x_0)\right\vert}{n!}\sup_{\xi\in(x_0,x)}\left\vert \frac{(x-\xi)^n\cdot f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{\varphi'(\xi)}\right\vert
$$
